# How can I make scrapy to download only a few urls even though there more than a few to crawl

Tags: scrapy

is there a command line switch or another out of the box trick to force scrapy to download only a few urls (even though there are more available?)

i am currently invoking a spider on the command like like below and would like it to finish after 10 url retrievals.

**scrapy crawl mySpider**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a setting to `scrapy`:

```
scrapy crawl mySpider -s CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT=10
```

- If the spider crawls more than `10`, the spider will be closed with the reason `closespider_pagecount`.

Comment: awesome! thx. is this feature documented somewhere? looked through the docs but couldn't find anything

Comment: @Jabb Take a look at: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.contrib.closespider